# Making SQLAlchemy records from a list

Tags: python, oop, python-2.7, for-loop, sqlalchemy

Fairly new to Python and very new to SQLAlchemy. Wondering how I can use a `for` loop to make multiple SQLAlchemy records from a list. Here's a very simplified version of what I have.

```
class ListItem(Base): 
    __tablename__ = list_items
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    item = Column(String(50))

def list_to_ListItem(list_of_things): 
    for thing in list_of_things: 
        listitem = ListItem()
        listitem.item = thing
```

I haven't yet run this because there's actually a lot more to my code that still needs to be worked out, but I'm under the impression that, instead of creating a record in `list_items` for each `thing` in `list_of_things`, this will simply create one record assigned to `listitem` that it will overwrite with every iteration of the for loop.

So how do I do this? Like I said, I'm fairly new to Python, but I've heard something about factory functions that I don't understand but which, at least in name, sounds promising for this problem. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[List comprehension](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions)?

```
list_items = [ListItem(item=thing) for thing in list_of_things]
```